# Arabic Support in Babel Mess up Chapter referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, arabic, books

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,main=english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}
We talked about the second chapter \ref{ch:poly}.

\section{start}
\section{end}

\chapter{Polyglot}
\label{ch:poly}
We talked about the first chapter \ref{ch:intro}.

\section{first}
\section{second}

\end{document}
```

Adding arabic support through babel leads to the following results:

[image: Chapter 2 is referenced as the last section of the first chapter]

[image: Chapter 1 reference is not shown at all!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in the redefinition of `\@chapter` done by `arabicore.sty`; the same bug is in the redefinition of `\@part`.

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl{\SAV@@part[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}}%
\else{\SAV@@part[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}}%
\fi} 

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl{\SAV@@chapter[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}}%
\else{\SAV@@chapter[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}}%
\fi}
```

What happens is that `\SAV@@chapter` (which is the original `\@chapter` command) is performed in a group, so upon exiting the group, the value of `\@currentlabel` set by `\refstepcounter{chapter}` is lost. Indeed, for `\ref{ch:poly}` you got 1.2, which is the number last assigned by `\section`.

Fix:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@@part[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}%
\else\SAV@@part[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}%
\fi} 

\def\@spart#1{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@spart{\textRL{#1}}%
\else\SAV@spart{\textLR{#1}}%
\fi}  

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@@chapter[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}%
\else\SAV@@chapter[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}%
\fi} 

\def\@schapter#1{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@schapter{\textRL{#1}}%
\else\SAV@schapter{\textLR{#1}}%
\fi}
```

I also changed the redefinitions of `\@spart` and `\@schapter`, although they aren't really involved. Other usages of `\if@rl` doesn't seem to be dangerous like the ones I fixed.

#### Full example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,main=english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@@part[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}%
\else\SAV@@part[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}%
\fi} 

\def\@spart#1{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@spart{\textRL{#1}}%
\else\SAV@spart{\textLR{#1}}%
\fi}  

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@@chapter[\textRL{#1}]{\textRL{#2}}%
\else\SAV@@chapter[\textLR{#1}]{\textLR{#2}}%
\fi} 

\def\@schapter#1{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\xstring\select@language{\main@Arabi@language}}%
\if@rl\SAV@schapter{\textRL{#1}}%
\else\SAV@schapter{\textLR{#1}}%
\fi}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}
We talked about the second chapter \ref{ch:poly}.

\section{start}
\section{end}

\chapter{Polyglot}
\label{ch:poly}
We talked about the first chapter \ref{ch:intro}.

\section{first}
\section{second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can report this to the maintainer?

Comment: There is an email address of Youssef Jabri in the documentation of `arabi` (do `texdoc arabi`), on the first page.

Comment: This solution seems specific to the arabicore.sty. The solution from Name worked for mine (different issue as I'm not assigning the arabic in the babel package), this one did not. Including the \label{} inside the \chapter{}.  \chapter{Example \label{ch: example}}

Comment: @João Name’s answer is a workaround that cures just the symptom and not the disease. But yes, my solution is specific to babel-arabic. If your setup is different, the disease is also different and it may warrant a specific question.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to solve the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction \label{ch:intro}}

We talked about the second chapter \ref{ch:poly}.

\section{start}
\section{end}

\chapter{Polyglot \label{ch:poly}}

We talked about the first chapter \ref{ch:intro}.

\section{first}
\section{second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it does, but `\label` should work also outside the chapter title.

Comment: You saved my day ! Thank you so much.